Comparision of bond length in synergic bonding
Below is a question from NSEC 2019:

The alkene ligand $(\pi\ce{-C2R4)}$ is both a $\pi$ donor and a $\pi$ acceptor, similar to the $\ce{CO}$ ligand in metal carbonyls, and exhibits synergic bonding with metals. Correct order of $\ce{C-C}$ bond length in $\ce{K[PtCl3(\pi}\ce{-C2R4)]}$ complexes in which $\ce{R = H, F}$ or $\ce{CN}$ is

The answer stated was $\ce{CN > F > H}$. The reason given was that due to more electron withdrawing nature of $\ce{–CN}$, the $\ce{C=C}$ bond length is maximum in case of $\ce{–CN}$
But isn't $\ce{F}$ more electronegative? Where am I going wrong?

Welcome to Chemistry SE! Can you confirm if you are particularly asking the reason behind more electron withdrawing character of CN than F? If it is so, consider changing the tags and language of your post. The reason for the same is that the CN system is conjugated with the alkene. (F doesn't have empty orbitals hence it cannot undergo back-bonding) Also note that CN has a higher -I effect than F

I wanted to know both of them. I thought that F is more electronegative so it would snatch more density of electron from metal but at the same time due to high EN it would not donate it's orbital thereby not forming strong sigma bond. And hence weaker synergic bond. I would love to get more insights. Thank u!

Also the back bonding which fluorine does not perform is of no relevance here because the carbon atom is doing the back bonding and taking the electrons from the metal. Fluorine or cyanide group is hair just increasing its tendency by making carbon electron deficient as they are very electronegative. Now carbon also does not have any empty orbital and here the bond are formed by $\pi$ antibonding molecular orbitals. This is what I found in my book.
